# Dumb C# Question, How is System and System.Text both namespaces

Tags: c#, nested, namespaces, system

How is System and System.Text both namespaces

---

Are they created as like nested namespaces

```
namespace System{
    Some Classes with Methods
    
    namespace Text{
        Some Classes with Methods
    }

    namespace Linq{
        Some Classes with Methods
    }
}
```

because text is nested inside of system you have to call it like

```
using System.Text;
```

----------------OR-----------------

are they created like

```
namespace System{
    Some Classes with Methods
}

namespace System.Text{
    Some Classes with Methods
}

namespace System.Linq{
    Some Classes with Methods
}
```

so when you call it you are calling it by it's actual namespace

```
using System.Text;
```

--------------OR----------------

or maybe it happens because it is written like

```
namespace System{
    Some Classes with Methods
}

using System;
namespace Text{
    Some Classes with Methods
}

using System;
namespace Linq{
    Some Classes with Methods
}
```

so because Text is using System you have to call it like

```
using System.Text;
```

-----------------OR--------------

Possibly some other way that I am not smart enough to think of

Comment: I don't think there is a "2nd is correct" @Charles - either 1 or 2 will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and second will behave the same. Namespaces are a bit like folders and classes are a bit like files. You could have your namespaces in a hierarchy like folders:

```
namespace System{
  namespace Text{
    class StringBuilder{
```

If you were trying to imagine this as a sequence of DOS commands it might be like every `namespace` is a `mkdir`, every `{` is a `cd` into it and every `}` is a `cd ..` out of it :

```
mkdir System               (Mkdir doesn't crash if a directory exists)
  cd System
  mkdir Text
    cd Text
    edit StringBuilder.cs
```

You could specify the full path in one hit:

```
namespace System.Text{
  class StringBuilder{
```

Which could be like

```
mkdir System\Text         (Yes, mkdir can accept a full path and will create every directory along the way)
  cd System\Text
  edit StringBuilder.cs
```

---

Your third is legal C# but not the same as the other two. Your third declares 3 root level namespaces called System, Text and Linq. A `using` statement is not like a DOS `cd` that "leaves you inside namespace X" it's more like "add namespace X to the search path so if you're looking for class Z you have another known path to search"

In DOS terms your third example is like

```
mkdir System
  cd System
  cd ..

path add System

mkdir Text
  cd Text
  cd ..

path add Text

mkdir Linq
  cd Linq 
  cd ..
```

You don't end up with a hierarchy of folders that way, you end up with 3 folders in C:\

You could write

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
```

But it would be a `Text.StringBuilder` not a `System.Text.StringBuilder` because it would be in c:\Text\StringBuilder.cs - it'd still be found when searched for because of the "path add Text" but adding a folder to a search path does not cause folders to be created inside other folders

<sub>The file/folder analogy eventually falls down because C# can have any number of classes inside any number of namespaces inside a single file named nothing to do with anything - heck, it could be Cdrive.cs and contain hundreds of classes and namespaces, but for this purpose it'll do..</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I very much appreciate it